# Problemas para fazer deploy no Heroku usando Jenkins (CI) (Credentials)

Tags: heroku, jenkins

Bom estou com um problema onde não estou conseguindo me conectar ao servidor do git do Heroku para poder dar um Push para o servidor. Estou utilizando o Jenkins como ferramenta de CI mas não encontrei uma maneira de usar o credentials para que ele conecte. Alguém poderia me ajudar.

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git.exe -c core.askpass=true ls- remote -h https://git.heroku.com/blabla HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: github --credentials get: github: command not found
github --credentials erase: github: command not found
remote: ! WARNING:
remote: ! Do not authenticate with username and password using git.
remote: ! Run `heroku login` to update your credentials, then retry the git command.
remote: ! See documentation for details: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-git#authentication
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.heroku.com/blabla/'
```

Vi um tutorial para tentar fazer o mesmo mais não deu muito certo, não.

[Link para o Exemplo](http://thediscoblog.com/blog/2014/01/24/continuous-delivery-for-heroku-with-jenkins/)

Comment: creio que vc não tenha o git instalado na maquina que esta rodando o jenkins